# Blocking direct URL access to a controller returning a partialview?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If one where to have a controller named UsersController with an action like:

```
public ActionResult ActiveUsers()
{
   IQueryable<TBL_USERS> recentUsers = repo.GetRecentUsers();
   Return PartialView(recentUsers);
}
```

And this is called via a `Html.RenderAction()` throughout the ap.

If a user were to navigate to Users/ActiveUsers directly in the address bar the partial view would be rendered in the browser.

Is it possible to block this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use ChildActionOnlyAttribute (http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)

```
  [ChildActionOnly]
  public ActionResult Menu() {
    var menu = GetMenuFromSomewhere();
      return PartialView(menu);
  }
```