# Block navigation to a partial View used as a modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a partial view we use as a modal box on our MVC5 app. We want people to click the link to get the modal, but not be able to navigate to the view itself. So we want to block this: http://localhost:63595/registration/forgot-password

I tried the suggestion here: [Blocking Direct URL Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934880/blocking-direct-url-access-to-a-controller-returning-a-partialview) which uses [ChildActionOnly], but that breaks the modal. The dialog box comes up but is empty, it only has the 'Close' button.

The link is coded like this:

```
<div class="login-bottom-link">
    <a href="#" onclick="getForm('Register','@Url.Action("Register", "Registration")')">Create Account</a>
     <span>|</span> 
    <a href="#" onclick="getForm('Forgot Password','@Url.Action("forgot-password", "Registration")')">Forgot Password?</a>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function getForm(title, urlAction) {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load(urlAction);
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[ChildActionOnly]` only makes sure the action is called through `Html.RenderAction`.

In your case, I don't think you can block it entirely since the browser has to make the request. Your best bet may be to check `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` in the controller action, and if it's false return an empty view. This can be bypassed by anyone determined enough to do it, but if it's not a security issue then it may be good enough.